# Creation of products in Hybris commerce using web services in SAP Data Services

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, sap-erp, sap-data-services

I've been trying to use SAP Data Services to integrate products from an existing ECC system into Hybris commerce platform, the data is ready to be pushed to the system but for the life of my I cannot get SAP Data Services to interface with the Hybris api for creating products.

Has anyone out there accomplished creating products in Hybris using Data Services and would have an example of the settings of the data store and structure of the function call in Data Services? Also are the WADLs avaliable for these services anywhere in Hybris?

Comment: As far as I know these services are meant to support alternative web shop frontends to the hybris accelerator storefront. They are not meant to maintain the system.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this was a top down decision to utilise these particular applications and web services, but I've managed to make it work. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybris preference async data transfer, so it is using IDOC for ECC via hybris data hub.

I haven't been using it but you can check ootb rest services or develop custom in hybris and call it from SAP Data Services.

Hybris doesn't support SOAP ootb so there is no WADL or WSDL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we ended up writing scripts and importing them as custom functions into SAP Data Services as per your advice